# How to manually set the page and total results on first load of Kendo UI Grid attached to a remote dataSource (autoBind:false)?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

A similiar question is posted on a forum **[here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/manually-specify-total-number-of-items)**, but with no answer.
 
A demonstration of the problem can be seen in this **[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4EDys/2/)**. Notice the page is 0 and it says "No items to display" for total pages.

For *progressive enhancement* reasons, 
My grid is initially loaded from an existing HTML table. This is good for SEO and is the true advantage of progressive enhancement. However, I want my Kendo Grid to use ajax to reload it's data (for such operations like sorting, pagination, etc). On initialization I set the dataSource to have a remote read url. This works great, but with one problem: it runs an unnecessary ajax call on the first load. Remember, I already generated the first set of data by reading from an existing HTML table...

To avoid the unnecessary first ajax call, I added `autoBind:false` to my grid initialization. But the side-effect is that now the grid incorrectly says page is `0` and the total number of pages shows `no items for display`.

What good is `autoBind` if you can't setup these elements on first load programmatically? **Any ideas on how I can suppress the first ajax call, and manually set the page number and total pages myself on first load?**

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
     sortable: true,
     pageable: true,
     resizable: true,
     selectable: "multiple",
     autoBind: false,
     dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "some url here",
            }
        },
        pageSize:40,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        schema: { 
                   data: "rows",
                   total: function(data){
                               return data.total;
                          }
                } 
     }
     columns: [{
                    field: "id",         
                    title: "ID",
                    width:3, 
                },{
                    field: "name",   
                    title: "Name",          
                    width:13, 
                },{
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `total` function defined in the `schema` says that you have field in the returned JSON which name is `total`. Is that true? So your JSON should look like:

```
{
    rows : [
        { id: 1, name: "name1" },
        { id: 2, name: "name2" },
        { id: 3, name: "name3" },
        { id: 4, name: "name4" }
    ],
    total : 4
}
```

Is this what your JSON looks like?

If you are actually not returning that JSON field called `total`, then you should define is as:

```
total, function (data) {
    return data.length;
}
```

For going to a specific page in the grid and since you are using `autoBind: false`, you should use:

```
grid.dataSource.query({ page: 3, pageSize: 40 });
```

Check it running here : http://jsfiddle.net/WNk6d/ you will see that the Grid is **not** initially loaded (`autoBind` equals false) and whenever you change the `numericTextBox` field, it loads the page that you want (not the first) and nothing happens until you change the numeric text box.

Comment: Have you tried using `autoBind: false;`. For me this works to suppress the first load via ajax. However if I run the code `grid.dataSource.page(3);` right after I initialize the grid, it ignores autoBind:false and makes an ajax call regardless.

Comment: Or better yet, when I add `page: 3` to the dataSource section of my grid initialization that I show in my question, nothing changes. Still shows pager on page `0`

Comment: Is there not a way for me to manually start the grid on a page, and give it the total amount of pages (but still have it set for a remote datasource that doesn't make an ajax call on first load)? I'm close to accomplishing this by creating the grid from an existing HTML table on first load. This is actually proper progressive enhancement. However I have no way to set the page number or total pages on the grid initially (without triggering a wasteful unnecessary initial ajax call)

Comment: Actually, checked again, yes `grid.dataSource.page(3)` does trigger the ajax...which negates the use of `autoBind:false`. I need to manually set the page and total pages on first load without making the ajax call. The data is already there (from the HTML table that the grid is created from). BTW, thanks for your help so far OnaBai. You have some good answers here on Kendo Grid that have helped me and I've +1 you! I'm just stuck for the moment with this problem...

Comment: Please, check http://jsfiddle.net/WNk6d/ on how to set `autoBind` to false and load the grid the specified page programmatically.

Comment: Now in that demo can you get it to load page 1 on first load of the page? That's my problem, I can't tell Kendo to say it's on page 1 with `autoBind:false`

Comment: Yes. Check http://jsfiddle.net/WNk6d/2/ you just need to invoke `$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.query({page: 1, pageSize: 20});`

Comment: Yes, but by doing that you invoke the ajax call, thus making the `autoBind:false;` useless. See my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/4EDys/2/ . Can you get this to show page 1 on first load (no ajax)?

Comment: Ok! I think that now I start understanding your problem, you want to have some static content but then being able to use a remote DataSource. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep! This is the true nature of progressive enhancement, and makes the grids friendly for SEO. And there's no point in making an intial ajax call when the data is already there.

Comment: Onabai, I've reworded my question a bit to be clearer. But you now correctly understand my problem. I'm eagerly awaiting your solution.

Comment: Try the solution below. AutoBind is of no use in yoursituation.

Comment: @DavidGraham, the only solutions that come to my mind is not having the initial content as HTML but as JSON inside the emitted page. But even with that it is not a clean solution. I'm assuming that you do this to save a second transaction, since you have to go to the server to get the HTML you already get some initial data. Correct? If you see KendoUI demo in their site about initializing a table form HTML they actually use only one page. I know how to get the page 1 displayed but the total would be NaN :-(

Comment: Yeah you are correct. You understand the situation. I was excited that so far I was able to do everything cleanly in Kendo Grid. But now I'm faced with having to "rig it" for the first time. So sad.

Comment: @OnaBai Can you update your answer, showing how to make the pagination part show correctly (even if it's a direct css/js method). I can always pass the information from my server side script that gives the current page number on first load (as well as the total count). I think this is a decent fix. I can also put this inside some global js file as a fix for all my Kendo Grids I use this way. As for the bottom right corner of total pages...I can always easily fix the text where it would say "NaN". That way I can accept your answer, for all your hard work!

Comment: Any luck on manually working with the pager? I'm trying to work a solution based on working with the pager directly. Not many examples of this though.

Comment: I don't think that what you are trying to do fits well in KendoUI Grid. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/4EDys/4/ just in case it might help you but this is far from complete. You will see that it initially shows page but not total.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I guess I'm going to just have to accept that redundancy hit for now. I'm not seeing an elegant solution that fits in well either. It wouldn't create very maintainable/readable code I think. +1 for your help!

Comment: Actually...I thought about it more. And because queries are expensive (and running them twice on page load is not going to be a viable option) and because good SEO is important as well...I think I'm left with possibly sending over the JSON to Kendo grid along with the HTML grid.

Comment: @OnaBai I think I've solved this problem, but I've hit another issue...I've created another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637507/how-to-update-a-kendo-grid-datasource-to-a-remote-url-but-without-triggering-an

Comment: I'm wondering if this can be done using an observable object.

Answer (score 1):

dataSource.query({
   page: 1,
   skip: 0,
   pageSize: 5
});

Comment: This does work, but note that it causes a read to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the read method of the Kendo grid DataSource on the page load.
**I have Used Ajax and yet it works...**

I have written a small script for this purpose.

```
$(function(){
         var dataSource = $("#LogLatestGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;

    $("#LogPanel").bind("shown", function(){
                dataSource.read();
            });
});
```

call this on you page load. And please change the names of the DOM elements.

Comment: Maxpan...notice that when you do this an ajax call is made immediately on page load. That's what I'm trying to avoid. It's an unnecessary and wasteful ajax call (when the data is already loaded).